# What are the ways to handle authentication for outlook mail api other than using owin middleware?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api

I have followed the following guide to implement oauth for outlook mail api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial

It uses Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) in combination with owin middle-ware to authenticate users.

I would essentially like to separate the authentication to be something that is done after the main authentication with a local db.. (seperate module for outlook).. The authenticated user can opt to use or not use outlook features in the app.

Would there be an easy way to achieve this other than manually (using http calls) doing authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily. You don't need OWIN to use MSAL. For example, you could get the login URL using `GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync` from the `ConfidentialClientApplication` class and use that to generate a login button or link. Then you'd just need to implement a redirect in your app to exchange the auth code for a token.